# CA Service Desk Web Service API : How to sort data using query

Tags: web-services, api, sorting, ca

I am trying to fetch data from CA service desk in a customized application. To fetch data:

SDProxy.doSelect() method is used.

I want to sort the data in service desk itself like we do in SQL. But I'm not able to find any solution.

Note: I found **sortBy** keyword which do not work with whereclause in service desk.